# Cannot open StoryBoard xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

Yesterday before I shutdown my mac, everything was ok. Till I opened it today and there seems to be an error with the StoryBoard.

Could not be opened,XMLparsecomment: invalid XMLchar value 16

Anyone Ideas why am I recieving this error and better how to fix it?

Comment: I don't know why the error happens, but can you post the content of the storyboard file somewhere? It probably can be fixed.

Comment: You can post the storyboard XML here or the storyboard file itself on some filesharing site

Comment: it says line 451 btw but when I open the file with notepad there only like 50 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say why this error has occurred. However, it should be possible to recover a previous "good" copy of the file, if you have been using either a version control system or system backups (preferably both). True, you may lose a little bit of work, but that's better than losing it all.

In case you don't already know:

Xcode 4 supports both git and Subversion for version control. Xcode will even ask if you want to create a local git repository when you create a project. Other systems, such as Mercurial can still be used; they just won't integrate with Xcode and you will need to check in and out using a separate application.

On OS X, there really isn't a good excuse for not using Time Machine.

Don't work without a safety net!